# Is there a 'variable_get' method? If not, how can I create my own?

Tags: ruby

courtesy of irb:

```
2.0.0-p0 :006 > @instance_variable = "from an instance variable"
 => "from an instance variable" 
2.0.0-p0 :007 > variable = "from a variable"
 => "from a variable" 
2.0.0-p0 :008 > instance_variable_get(:@instance_variable)
 => "from an instance variable" 
2.0.0-p0 :009 > variable_get(:variable)
NoMethodError: undefined method `variable_get' for main:Object
    from (irb):9
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
2.0.0-p0 :010 >
```

I'm simply trying to programmatically 'query' for a variable and return its contents. Exactly like instance_variable_get but for a variable.

It's for a custom rspec matcher. Not some crazy workaround :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Ruby 2.1 and later, you can use [`Binding#local_variable_get`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get).

In prior versions of Ruby, you have to use `eval`. If you want to do some sanity-checking before evaluating a supposed variable name, you can check whether the named variable is in `local_variables`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval`:

```
irb(main):007:0> variable = "from a variable"
=> "from a variable"
irb(main):008:0> eval 'variable'
=> "from a variable"
```

Comment: Of course! I've been conditioned so thoroughly to avoid eval like the plague I didn't think. I think it would be fine in this context.

Comment: `eval` isn't inherently evil. Using `eval` on data that came from unknown sources is. If the data is coming from a user's input, then you have to scrub it, or have a way of running it in a sandbox where it can't cause problems. If you, or your program, is the source of the data, then using eval is fine, such as when you want to know the value of a particular local variable.